# What benefits to create Telegram channel for channel owner?

Tags: telegram, messenger

There are a lot of useful Telegram messenger channels, groups on topic healthy, ecommerce and etc. . My question is that how owner gets benefit from this channel ? For example: I subscribed to channel about Telegram channel about healthy, and it pushes everyday 1 or 2 useful contents, why they do it ? Who pays them for ? or it's just spending time ?

Answer (score 1):

**No benefits** for create trending channel at all, they can't get money like YouTube subscription.

I think they provide their content because they have no popular blog for now, Telegram is general way to distribute their content, this can be a sense of achievement.

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons to have a channel:

1. a branded company can notify their users about their news, special sales, ...

I know a website called Digikala.com which its special sales are being sold out in few minutes.(one of their best tools for notifying potential customers is their telegram channel)

2. you can have a general(or special purpose) channel ranging from news, sports, jokes, clips, ... to managament, recruitment, ... and after getting some users, you can gather ads and make money! that simple!
   I know some channels that are making thousands of dollars each day!!